# Norm of rotation matrix as element in $M_2(A)$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a complex unital Banach algebra and let $R_t=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{\pi t}{2} & -\sin\frac{\pi t}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\pi t}{2} & \cos\frac{\pi t}{2} \end{pmatrix}$. If I consider $M_2(A)$ with the operator norm coming from $A^2$ equipped with the norm $||(a,b)||=\sqrt{||a||^2+||b||^2}$, what is the norm of $R_t$ as an element of $M_2(A)$?

I was tempted to say it is 1 but I realized that it's probably not so straightforward. An upper bound would do as well (for example, is there an upper bound on the norm of an arbitrary matrix in $M_2(A)$ in terms of the norms of the entries?)

This should be a rather simple problem but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It would help me understand this if you would please define the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ on $A^2$.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertLewis: I'm assuming it is the usual $\|(a,b)\|_2 = \sqrt{\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2}$, where the norms under the square root are the native norm of $A$.

Comment: @Hennin Makholm:  I suspect as much myself!

Comment: Yes, that is it. I've edited the post to specify the norm.

Comment: The functional calculus might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

It works out the same way as in the real case (and the operator norm is 1) -- we just have to be a little more careful than usual. <s>The following holds whenever $A$ is a normed real vector space, and $A^2=A\oplus A$ is equipped with the derived 2-norm:</s>

Derive an inner product from the norm on $A^2$ in the usual way through the polarization identity:
$$\langle v,w\rangle = \frac12(\|v+w\|^2-\|v\|^2-\|w\|^2)$$

**EDIT: Argh, this is not possible in general -- only if the original norm on $A$ satisfies the parallelogram identity. That pretty much kills the rest of the answer in the general case.**

It has all the usual nice properties -- in particular we can see by direct calculation that
$$ \tag{*} \left\langle\bigl[{}^p_0\bigr],\bigl[{}^0_q\bigr]\right\rangle = 0 $$
for all $p,q\in A$. Due to the symmetry of $\|{\cdot}\|$ in the two coordinates we also have
$$ \tag{**} \left\langle\bigl[{}^p_q\bigr],\bigl[{}^r_s\bigr]\right\rangle =
\left\langle\bigl[{}^q_p\bigr],\bigl[{}^s_r\bigr]\right\rangle$$

Let $v=(a,b)$ and $w=R_t v$. If for brevity we set $c=\cos\frac{\pi t}{2}$ and $s=\sin\frac{\pi t}{2}$ we get
$$ w = c\bigl[{}^a_0\bigr]
- s\bigl[{}^b_0\bigr]
+ s\bigl[{}^0_a\bigr]
+ c\bigl[{}^0_b\bigr] $$
Now expand $\|w\|^2 = \langle w,w\rangle$ by linearity on both sides, and similarly move the $s$ and $c$ factors out in front. Of the 16 this produces, 8 vanish immediately due to $(*)$ and 4 of the rest (the cross terms such as $-sc\langle\bigl[{}^a_0\bigr],\bigl[{}^b_0]\rangle$) cancel each other due to $(**)$. This canceling is where using an inner product really pays off; it allows us to pull the minus sign on one of the sines in the matrix *out of* the inner product so it can cancel the other sine, which wouldn't have been possible when working with norms all of the way.

What is left is
$$ \begin{align} \|w\|^2 &= c^2\left\|(a,0)\right\|^2
+ s^2\left\|(b,0)\right\|^2
+ s^2\left\|(0,a)\right\|^2
+ c^2\left\|(0,b)\right\|^2 \\
&= (c^2+s^2)\|a\|^2+(c^2+s^2)\|b\|^2 \\
&= \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2 = \|v\|^2
\end{align}$$
So the operator norm is indeed $1$.

Comment: Very nice indeed; I too was thinking of somehow manifesting an inner product on $A$.  +1!

Comment: I didn't think of using an inner product. Nice answer. I'd just like to ask one other question. If I change the norm on $A^2$ to $||(a,b)||=\max(||a||,||b||)$, am I right to say that $||R_t||=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @learner: We have $\|v\|_\infty \le \|v\|_2 \le \sqrt2 \|v\|_\infty$, so $$\|R_t v\|_\infty \le \|R_t v\|_2 = \|v\|_2 \le \sqrt2 \|v\|_\infty$$ and thus $\|R_t\|_\infty \le \sqrt2$. Whether $\sqrt2$ is actually reached depends on $t$. When $t=1/8$ it is, but on the other hand we clearly have $\|R_0\|=1$.

Comment: @learner: Oops, all of this doesn't actually work in general. I was wrong in assuming that the polarization identity _always_ creates an inner product from a norm.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I guess you need the norm to satisfy the parallelogram law for it to work.